# Stored Procedures aren't replicated in Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge-replication

I am replicating a database using merge and had an issue where if the developers changed a procedure on the original database the change would not be pushed to the replicated database.  Replicate schema changes is set to True.

Any guidance reason why the changes don't replicate?  I did a snapshot before initiating replication.  The developers claim it has worked in the past, though I am skeptical because it should not I believe.

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In merge replication,

Replicate schema changes set to TRUE means DDL changes of the merge tables are getting replicated ( e.g. ADD/REMOVE COLUMNS).

Other objects such as view,stored procedure,function etc changes can never be replicated using merge replication.

Comment: How would you get a procedure to copy up to another database?

Comment: Bad question.  I am getting this error when trying to manually change the procedure now.

The data definition language (DDL) command cannot be executed at the Subscriber. DDL commands can only be executed at the Publisher. In a republishing hierarchy, DDL commands can only be executed at the root Publisher, not at any of the republishing Subscribers.
The schema change failed during execution of an internal replication procedure. For corrective action, see the other error messages that accompany this error message.
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Comment: This answer has been out-of-date for a long time. Merge replication of stored procs has been supported since SQL Server 2016: "Publishing Stored Procedures: All types of replication allow you to replicate stored procedure definitions... Changes to procedures are replicated to Subscribers."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/publish-data-and-database-objects?view=sql-server-2016#publishing-stored-procedures

Comment: NOTE: just did a test under a 2012 version I still have running and confirmed that merge replication of stored proc changes was working under that version as well.